# MSAccess query taking too long to execute

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have Access 2003 with SQL backend.

This query takes 10 minutes to execute and if I take out the Exists part it takes 10 sec.

I can't put it in SQL as a passthrough query because I need it in a Access subreport.

Any ideas how to improve execution time??

```
SELECT DailyLeaveLedger.dldEmployeeID, 
       Sum(IIf([tolAnnualLeaveType]<>0,1,0)) AS ALDays, 
       Sum(IIf([tolPersonalLeaveType]<>0,1,0)) AS PLDays, 
       Sum(IIf([tolPublicHolidayType]<>0,1,0)) AS PHDays, 
       DailyLeaveLedger.dldPHID

FROM (DailyLeaveLedger 
      INNER JOIN Employees ON DailyLeaveLedger.dldEmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID)   
      INNER JOIN TypeOfLesterLeave ON DailyLeaveLedger.dldLeaveType = TypeOfLesterLeave.tolID

WHERE (((DailyLeaveLedger.dldAuthDecline)=1) AND 
       ((DailyLeaveLedger.dldAuthorisedBy) Is Not Null) AND 
       ((DailyLeaveLedger.dldReleaseToPayroll)=True) AND 
       ((IIf([forms]![TransferTBRToPayrollForm]![chkOnlyPayLeave]=True,
                Exists (SELECT DISTINCT InvoiceHeader.InvDate 
                        FROM (InvoiceHeader 
                         INNER JOIN ReceiptDetail ON InvoiceHeader.InvNumber = ReceiptDetail.RDInvNumber) 
                         INNER JOIN [Work Codes] ON ReceiptDetail.RDWorkCodeID = [Work Codes].WorkCodeID 
                        WHERE ((ReceiptDetail.RDPayRun=0 Or 
                                ReceiptDetail.RDPayRun Is Null) AND 
                               (ReceiptDetail.RDRctToPayrollFlag=0) AND 
                               ([Work Codes].WorkCodePayrollAccount1<>0) AND 
                               (InvoiceHeader.EmployeeID = DailyLeaveLedger.dldEmployeeID) AND 
                              (DailyLeaveLedger.dldLeaveDate > DateAdd("ww", -InvoiceHeader.InvWeeksOfPay, InvoiceHeader.InvBeginDate)) AND 
                              (DailyLeaveLedger.dldLeaveDate <= InvoiceHeader.InvBeginDate)))
             ,True))=True))
GROUP BY DailyLeaveLedger.dldEmployeeID, DailyLeaveLedger.dldPHID
HAVING (((DailyLeaveLedger.dldPHID) Is Null));
```

Comment: What makes you think a pass-through query prohibits using it in a subreport? Not that it matters since it will probably perform just as badly as a pass-through.

Comment: I see what you are saying now. You have embedded controls in the query which would prevent a pass-through from working. However, you have bigger problems. The Exists clause nested in an iif means it runs on every row. You are gonna habe to rework this to get rid of the exists and iif block. If you explain what it is trying to do I might be able to help you rework it.

Comment: It is trying to select leave days from a table and the exists is for to  only to select leave rows where the leave falls in range of an invoice. ie the time the invoice covers, if this makes sense.

Comment: I get an error when trying to run the report saying can't use pass through query in subreport.

Comment: Given that you have an SQL backend, would it be possible to move the query there and break it up into more manageable chunks (views, SP etc) and leverage what the server can do for you?

Answer (score 2):

Let's do this a little at a time. I'll update the answer as I find more:

First the easy one, get rid of the iif statements in the select as follows.

Replace

```
SELECT DailyLeaveLedger.dldEmployeeID, 
       Sum(IIf([tolAnnualLeaveType]<>0,1,0)) AS ALDays, 
       Sum(IIf([tolPersonalLeaveType]<>0,1,0)) AS PLDays, 
       Sum(IIf([tolPublicHolidayType]<>0,1,0)) AS PHDays, 
       DailyLeaveLedger.dldPHID
```

with

```
SELECT DailyLeaveLedger.dldEmployeeID, 
       Sum([tolAnnualLeaveType] *-1) AS ALDays, 
       Sum([tolPersonalLeaveType] *-1) AS PLDays, 
       Sum([tolPublicHolidayType] *-1) AS PHDays, 
       DailyLeaveLedger.dldPHID
```

This will give you minimum improvement. Once I untangle the rest I'll give you some more impactful ones.

The rest of this is such an unholy mess, I'm giving up on trying to unravel it. However, let me give you some guidance about what you need to do in a general sense instead of exact code.

**Essentially what you need to do is pull this part into the joins on the main query instead of using a subquery.**

```
(IIf([forms]![TransferTBRToPayrollForm]![chkOnlyPayLeave]=True,
                Exists (SELECT DISTINCT InvoiceHeader.InvDate 
                        FROM (InvoiceHeader 
                            INNER JOIN ReceiptDetail ON InvoiceHeader.InvNumber = ReceiptDetail.RDInvNumber) 
                            INNER JOIN [Work Codes] ON ReceiptDetail.RDWorkCodeID = [Work Codes].WorkCodeID 
                        WHERE ((ReceiptDetail.RDPayRun=0 Or ReceiptDetail.RDPayRun Is Null) AND 
                               (ReceiptDetail.RDRctToPayrollFlag=0) AND 
                               ([Work Codes].WorkCodePayrollAccount1<>0) AND 
                              (InvoiceHeader.EmployeeID = DailyLeaveLedger.dldEmployeeID) AND 
                              (DailyLeaveLedger.dldLeaveDate > DateAdd("ww", -InvoiceHeader.InvWeeksOfPay, InvoiceHeader.InvBeginDate)) AND 
                              (DailyLeaveLedger.dldLeaveDate <= InvoiceHeader.InvBeginDate)))
             ,True))=True))
```

Does that make sense? I'm frankly a little worried you are going to be able to pull this off if you aren't understanding why it is complaining about changing this to a pass-through. It has nothing to do with it being called from a sub-report and more to do with the fact that you are using VBA functions.

Comment: When I created it as a pass through I obviously were not referencing Access VBA functions and report fields. I created 2 stored procedures one with exists part and one with out exists part. Then in my VBA code changed the sql of the pass through query to call the stored proc I wanted depening on my form parameters. The stored proc with the EXISTS part executes in a few seconds. When I run the report a Access dialog pops up sayin 'You can't use a pass-through query or a non fixed columncrosstab query as a record source to a subform or subreport'.

Comment: Regarding  your suggestion about the IIF statements, I find my approach more readable and even though your way may save fractions of a second. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: IIF is a VBA function. I may be mistaken on the fields, I was mistakenly assuming that some of those bracketed values referred to a form or report. Like I said, this thing is a little obfuscated without prior knowledge of your DB structure.

Comment: Ahh the confusion is the passthrough query was not passing SQL but calling the stored proc.

Comment: It's your code, but remember that IIF is the most evil of all VBA functions. The non-shortcutting logic is a never-ending source of performance and logic bugs. In the case of queries against a SQL back-end it will also introduce overhead because it isn't ANSI SQL.

Comment: @JohnFx: "It's your code, but remember that IIF is the most evil of all VBA functions" -- in context, IIF() is an Access Database Engine SQL expression and in this context IIF() does indeed shortcut.

Comment: ... try this: SELECT IIF(FALSE, 0 / 0, 1 / 1);

Comment: ... or this: SELECT IIF(TRUE, 1 / 1, 0 / 0);

Comment: @onedaywhen: Run Time Error: Overflow for both of your examples.

Comment: Ahh, but wait. You are right. In the context of a query both return the expected values. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Please give us the formatted query for the better understanding..
I have gone through the query and found the reason may be due to **EXIST** statement where you are using **Distinct** clause for **InvoiceHeader.InvDate**

i dont know your exact scenario if you are using Exist clause only for record existance then use count(InvoiceHeader.InvDate) in place of distinct InvoiceHeader.InvDate 
i think then performance will increase..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what Access is doing underneath, but subreports are going to execute your query for each record in the main report, so I would take this query and dump it to a table before running the report. Then use the table for the subreport recordsource.

I've used this in a quarterly statement report that had several sub reports and it cut the time down from several hours to under 20 minutes.